# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) virtual machine with Vagrant on OS X provides only 4 Gb disk space

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, virtualization, partitioning, vagrant

I used the Vagrant image for Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit from  http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/raring/current/raring-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box to create a new virtual machine on my MacBook (10.8) and can successfully ssh to it. The problem is that though VirtualBox shows the size of the virtual machine's hard drive to be 40 Gb (dynamic), `df-h` command executed within the virtual machine shows that /dev/sda1 has only 4Gb, which is not enough for my needs:

`/dev/sda1       4.0G  970M  2.8G  26% /`

How can I ensure that my the Vagrant Ubuntu VM has enough space (e.g. 20Gb) on its sda1 partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with this specific Vagrant image. I've used a different one (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/547671/thinkstack-raring64.box) and there the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Those are automatically built Vagrant Ubuntu Cloud Images, we have no control over how they were built.

You either build your own vagrant box or 1. resize existing virtual HDD 2. Attach additional virtual HDDs, create file systems and mount it (e.g. /ops and install new stuff in this directory).

Personally I think option 2 is easier.

If you want to go with option 1, you'll have to convert the existing virtual HDD (VMDK) to VDI, because `VBoxManage modifyhd` only works with native VDI image. However, vagrant base boxes are basically exported OVF/OVA using VMDK format.

See VirtualBox Docs

> The --resize x option (where x is the desired new total space in
>   megabytes) allows you to change the capacity of an existing image;
>   this adjusts the logical size of a virtual disk without affecting the
>   physical size much.[37] This currently works only for VDI and VHD
>   formats, and only for the dynamically allocated variants, and can only
>   be used to expand (not shrink) the capacity.

#### Steps to increase the capacity of disk for Vagrant Base Box

1. To be able to resize the HDD, you'll have to covert it to VDI first, e.g. `VBoxManage clonehd in.vmdk out.vdi --format VDI` and then re-attached it (using the GUI is easy).
2. Resize it using `VBoxManage modifyhd box.vdi --resize 15360` which
   increase the capacity to 15GB.
3. However this only changes the drive capacity, you will have to grow the file system for the guest afterwards. For example, use `resize2fs -p -F DEVICE` for ext4.

Refer to the answer here for more details => [How can I increase disk size on a Vagrant VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317338/how-can-i-increase-disk-size-on-a-vagrant-vm/318711)

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I believe, I have a problem of a different kind. I cannot resize my virtual disk to be, e.g. 40Gb, since VirtualBox tells me that it is already 40Gb: VBoxManage `showhdinfo box-disk1.vdi` shows Logical size: 40960 MBytes. Also, when I try running `sudo resize2fs -p -F /dev/sda1` within the VM I get: `The filesystem is already 1048320 blocks long. Nothing to do!`. So the problem remains - VirtualBox believes the size of the virtual disk is 40Gb and the VM thinks it is 4Gb. My colleague has tried to deploy the same box on his MacBook and is facing the same problem.

Comment: The VM thinks that the size of the sda1 partition is 4G, but a partition is only part of the disk. Consider using parted or similar tools to resize the partition to fill the disk, and onlythen use resize2fs.